# How to switch to normal edit mode in JetBrains IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

At the beginning of using IDE, selected vim edit mode. How to switch back to normal mode?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "selected vim edit mode"? Do you mean that you are using the IdeaVim plugin and you'd like to stop using that plugin? i.e. rebind keystrokes etc to non vim actions?

Comment: Yes, I want to stop using the default Vim Emulation plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable the Vim emulator, you'll see this under the `Tools` menu or you can find it in the `Actions` popup:

[image]

Or you could disable the `IdeaVim` plugin by unticking the box in `Preferences > Plugins > IdeaVIM`:

[image]